# python/django problem with sessions and language

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following problem: on the main page I can change language. New language is saved in request.session['django_language']. I also have SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN set to my site, so session should be inherited by subdomains. And it is, because after changing language I check request.session['django_language'] in subdomains and it's fine. Then I use

django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware

to translate my pages. And it works perfectly... only on main site! If I change language and refresh main site - it is ok. However, if I change language and go to a subpage (for example /LogIn), then the page is NOT translated at all. It stays on default language. This is really strange, because if I use

{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as lang %}

in this subpage, then lang is good language. There is no mistake. What kind of problem can it be? Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using ugettext was the problem. I changed to ugettext_lazy and now it works perfectly fine. For some reason ugettext translates with old language. It works fine now.